# Hide Calendar of Datepicker when clicking outside in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to create a customized datepicker. The traditional one only opens the calendar when users click on the calendar icon. What I want to achieve is that users can open the calendar whenever they click on either the text or the icon. Following is my code. Everything works as expected. The only drawback is when users want to close the calendar, they have to click on the Red `Stackpanel` again. I want the calendar to disappear when they click outside of the datepicker as well. I tried adding `LostFocus` event for the Red `Stackpanel` but it does not work. Does anyone have a solution? I'd appreciate any help. Thank you

XAML file:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker" 
            SelectedDate="{Binding ApptNotScheduledStartDate}" 
            SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" >
    <DatePicker.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePicker">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_Click" 
                            Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red"  
                            Height="33" LostFocus="StackPanel_LostFocus">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ApptNotScheduledStartDate, StringFormat='{}{0:MMM dd, yyyy}'}" />
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ChevronDown"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" 
                        IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
                        <Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding ApptNotScheduledStartDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </DatePicker.Template>
</DatePicker>
```

Code behind:

```
        private void TextBlock_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MyDatePicker.IsDropDownOpen = !MyDatePicker.IsDropDownOpen;
        }

        private void DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyDatePicker.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }

        private void StackPanel_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyDatePicker.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `LostFocus` approach you were trying, you can handle `MyDatePicker`'s `MouseMove` event and check if the mouse is over `MyDatePicker`:

```
private void MyDatePicker_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

    HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MyDatePicker, pt);

    if (result != null)
        MyDatePicker.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    else
        MyDatePicker.IsDropDownOpen = false;
}
```

**Edit**

You can apply this same technique to check if the user has clicked outside `MyDatePicker` in the Window (or User Control) MouseDown event:

```
private void root_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

    HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MyDatePicker, pt);

    if (result == null)
        MyDatePicker.IsDropDownOpen = false;
}
```

Here `root`is the name of my Window.

Comment: It sounds good but what I want to do is to make it disappear only users "click" outside of the calendar or the Datepicker.

Comment: @MayNguyen you can use the same technique to check if the user clicked outside of `MyDatePicker`, see updates to answer.